# Python-how to print all rows of my csv file then recall my function?

Tags: python, csv

```
elif option == "3":
    with open('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoFile:
         classinfoFileReader = csv.reader(classinfoFile)
         for row in classinfoFileReader:
            print(row)
            schoolmenu()
```

This code works perfectly, but when I recall my function under 'print(row)' it the only print the first row of the csv file (bearing in mind that there is 25 lines of code to print). When I take out the function (schoolmenu()) it works how I want it to but as soon as I put it in only the forst row prints. How can I recall the function aswell as having all 25 rows of the file printed??

Comment: You haven't shown the code for schoolmenu(), so we have no idea why it doesn't return from it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function inside of the `for` loop.  When it hits the for loop it prints the first line then calls the function again.  Try:

```
elif option == "3":
    with open('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoFile:
         classinfoFileReader = csv.reader(classinfoFile)
         for row in classinfoFileReader:
            print(row)
    schoolmenu()
```

Comment: Thank you so much James, that was exactly the problem

Comment: Please remember to mark the question as answered (the check mark) if you feel the solution is complete.